# How to Split by Various Symbols Using Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

I have this simple file:

```
1|2|234 A=Jim 33
1|2|765 A=Sam 44
1|2|561 A=Edy 55
```

I want to parse the file to get the following output:

```
["1","2","Jim 33"]
["1","2","Sam 44"]
["1","2","Edy 55"]
```

I tried to split by "|", but the problem I am facing is how to split by "A=" or how to make the program recognizes "A=" and prints what is after it.

The algorithm that I have in mind is to iterate through each split item and check if the item contains the character "A=".  Not sure how to translate that into python code.  Any pythonic idea?

Comment: You could use a regex, like so: `(\d)\|(\d)\|(\d{3}) A=(.+)`, then get the groups.

Comment: Does each line always have the same length for each part? Or might there be a line with, say, `AC=Alice`?

Comment: Thank you for asking... The length of the lines are not consistent ... The sample of the file I put is simplistic ... Any idea how to tackle this issue? @TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regular expression, [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('\|| A=', '1|2|234 A=Jim 33')
['1', '2', '234', 'Jim 33']
```

`\|| A=` will match `|` or `A=`. The first `|` was escaped because `|` has special meaning in regular expression (meaning OR).